# Error in wordpress installation on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, lamp

I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-lamp-on-ubuntu-16-04) to install wordpress locally on my laptop, running Ubuntu 16.04
When I try to access my IP with my browser I get the following message.

```
  <?php
 /**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything,but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

 /**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
 define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

 /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
 require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'var/www/html/wordepress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I have tried to install wordpress in another directory or to download it again but the error remains.
Also I have been searching for this error but all the answers are about installations on servers, not locally. Does anyone have any idea what I should do?

Comment: What's the URL in the browser? Also, that last line doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: That's not an error message. That's php code.

Comment: I know it is not exactly an error, but still I can't access the admin panel. The url is my IP 127.0.0.1/